# Getting "Library not loaded, image not found" on armv7 devices only; suspecting App Thinning

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application built with Xcode 7.3.1. A recent update to this application added the Taplytics framework and support for iOS9 and watchOS2.

Using Crashlytics distribution, my QA team and beta testers have successfully ran the application on armv7, armv7s and arm64 devices.

The application was approved to the store last night and today, devices that have an armv7 architecture (iPhone 5, iPhone 5c) fail to load the app.

The error I pulled from the crash logs of a device is as follows:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: @rpath/Taplytics.framework/Taplytics | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/D5061E93-214B-4F24-8E06-CBA64C9B0940/XXXX.app/XXXX | Reason: image not found
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

The error occurs before any application code is loaded, as the OS is loading the App's bundle.

This same device runs a debug build direct from Xcode or a Release build through Crashlytics without issue.

I used lipo to verify that the IPA sent to the App Store contains an armv7 image, both for the main app and the Taplytics precompiled framework using:

```
lipo -info XXXX.app/Frameworks/Taplytics.framework/Taplytics
```

and I do get back a result confirming armv7, armv7s and arm64 support present in the bundle.

Since this is our first version with watchOS2, we've had to turn on Bitcode support in the app, which results in App Thinning happening when a client requests the App from the store.

I'm at a loss as to why the App Store distribution process would thin out armv7 support but it's the only possibility that I currently see.

However, I doubt I would be the first to encounter this and I am not seeing anything online to back up my claim.

What could be another possible cause of not having the proper image in this library considering:

- The IPA sent to the App Store contains armv7 support (according to lipo) for Taplytics
- Only armv7 (iPhone 5, iPhone 5c) clients get the error
- A release built from the same source and settings distributed through Crashlytics works properly on armv7 devices.

Comment: Would you mind posting your valid architectures and architectures for both Pods targets and your app target?

Comment: Add your framework to 'Embedded Binaries' in general setting tab of your project, it will solve your problem. @FJ de Brienne

Comment: @iOSAddicted For reference, valid architectures for Pod and App targets were correctly set. The Taplytics library was "requiring" a minimal device of arm64 through it's Info.plist instead of requiring it's minimal build target, armv7.

Comment: @KAR Since this was a pod-managed library, I prefer not to mingle with this. We might have been able to take it out of the pods and embed it as you propose in the project. However, the solution proposed by MobileBen (accepted answer) resolved the issue and allowed us to continue keeping this library pod-managed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Info.plist` for Taplytics, take a look at you're `Required Device Capabilities` aka `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`. Ensure all your architectures are listed. If not, then when app thinning has occurred, that slice will not be included.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Taplytics is installed through a Pod and doesn't have an Info.plist as part of the project.

Comment: I had a second look and the generated binary does indeed contain an Info.plst in the Taplytics framework. Where is this coming from? Investigating more...

Comment: Every framework should have an `Info.plist`. Did you examine it and notice that not all arch are defined? They should exist. You can go to your Pods directory in the terminal and run the find command. `find . -name Info.plist`

Comment: Thanks @ben, you were right. The Taplytics info.plist was listing arm64 as the Required Device Capabilities instead of armv7 which was more restrictive than it's binary. Changing this to armv7 allows App Thinning to keep the required armv7 architecture when deploying to an armv7 device.

Comment: @FJdeBrienne you'll need all your arch defined there. As an FYI, on an app I'm working on, we had the same crash you did (iPhone 5c, etc). We managed to talk to Apple about this, and they cited the Info.plist as the culprit. It is an issue on their end, since they really should detect the inconsistency rather than having the app thinning remove the needed slice ;).

Comment: thanks for the heads up. I feel, as you do, that this is definitely something that automated app review could catch and should warn you about, rejecting the binary. I'll modify the list to include all architectures according to your suggestion. Lesson learnt: Use TestFlight instead of Crashlytics when verifying the last builds before submission to faithfully reproduce app thinning...